# How to save different file paths to multiple variables in powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell form with a Browse button that is used to pick out a file and then the path to that file is saved into a textbox variable and displayed in the form. That part works fine, however, I have 3 text boxes that I'd like have filled in independently of each other, each with their own file path if the user decides to pick 3 different files. Make sense?

Here's the code...

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
[void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

If ($networktext1.Text -eq "") { $networktext1.Text = $OpenFileDialog.FileName }
If ($networktext2.Text -eq "") { $networktext2.Text = $OpenFileDialog.FileName }
If ($networktext3.Text -eq "") { $networktext3.Text = $OpenFileDialog.FileName }
If (($networktext1.Text -ne "") -and ($networktext2.Text -ne "") -and ($networktext3.Text -ne "")) { $logbox.Items.Add(" ERROR: No network slots available") }
```

I've played around with it every way I can think of and I can't get it to only fill in the first box, or if that one is taken only fill in the second box and so on. Obviously the code above will fill in all 3 boxes the first time a file is chosen and then give the error that they're all full. I brought it back to that point so it'd be easier to follow and modify with possible solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Second and third `If` -> `ElseIf`. Forth `If (condition)` -> `Else`.

Comment: Well I feel stupid now, lol. That makes sense and it works, thanks!